# How to uniquely number rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I'm using a composite primary key in a table like

```
CREATE TABLE t
ADD firstId INT,
ADD secondId INT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (firstId, secondId)
ADD KEY...,
ADD FOREIGN KEY...,
...
```

and want to switch to using a surrogate primary key instead. For this, I need to generate unique values for existing rows. I don't want to use autoincrement as future `id`s get generated using `hibernate_sequence`. There are just 10k rows, so speed hardly matters, but I'm curious, if there's something simpler than just loading all the rows and updating them one by one (that's pretty tedious as I can't use hibernate since it has to be done before the session factory gets created).

I can't use any formula like `firstId + N * secondId` as it wouldn't fit in the INT range (and I don't want to use longer IDs).

Something like

```
UPDATE t SET id = row_number + 1
```

would be perfect, but there's no `row_number` in MySQL.

So how can I uniquely number rows in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and then drop the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option.

Assuming the following schema and data:

```
create table t (
  firstId int not null,
  secondId int not null,
  primary key (firstId, secondId),
  index (secondId, firstId)
);

insert into t(firstId, secondId) values (1, 1);
insert into t(firstId, secondId) values (1, 2);
insert into t(firstId, secondId) values (2, 1);
insert into t(firstId, secondId) values (2, 2);
```

Execute the following queries:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;

alter table t drop primary key;
alter table t add unique key (firstId, secondId);
alter table t add column id int auto_increment primary key first;
alter table t modify id int not null;

set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Now the table will contain:

```
| id  | firstId | secondId |
| --- | ------- | -------- |
| 1   | 1       | 1        |
| 2   | 1       | 2        |
| 3   | 2       | 1        |
| 4   | 2       | 2        |
```

And the table schema will be:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `secondId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `firstId` (`firstId`,`secondId`),
  KEY `secondId` (`secondId`,`firstId`)
)
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5qEvdZ834DJeXycTiceTHM/0)

Note: You only need to disable the `foreign_key_checks`, if the current PRIMARY KEY is used by a foreign key.

Comment: Wow! `auto_increment` is smarter than I thought. Fantastic answer, I've learnt a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate it in some way - you might want to try [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//$SITEURL$/help/deleted-answers)